# IOptions not getting the values from appsettings.Development.json

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, api-gateway

I am trying to create a gateway api using net core. When I try to redirect the call using app.route :

```
app.Run(async (context) =>
            {
                using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
                {
                    var routing = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetService<IRoutingService>();

                    var content = await routing.RouteRequest(context.Request);
                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(await content.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    content.Dispose();

                    // Seed the database.
                }
            });
```

... And RoutingService service starts like :

```
public class RoutingService : IRoutingService
    {
        private readonly RouteManagement _routeManagement;
        static HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
        public RoutingService(IOptions<RouteManagement> routeManagement)
        {
            _routeManagement = routeManagement.Value;
        }
...
```

.. I can not get the values from json file filled. The following is the json file :

```
{

  "tokenManagement": {
    "secret": "Any String used to sign and verify JWT Tokens,  Replace this string with your own Secret",
    "issuer": "threenine.co.uk",
    "audience": "SampleAudience",
    "accessExpiration": 30,
    "refreshExpiration": 60
  },
  "routeManagement": {
    "Routes": [
      {
        "Endpoint": "/coupons",
        "Destination": {
          "Uri": "http://localhost:30561/coupons/",
          "RequiresAuthentication": "true"
        }
      },
      {
        "Endpoint": "/songs",
        "Destination": {
          "Uri": "http://localhost:8091/songs/",
          "RequiresAuthentication": "false"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Am I doing smth wrong? The following is the class RouteManagement

```
public class RouteManagement
{
    public List<Routes> Routes { get; set; }
}
public class Routes
{
    public string Endpoint { get; set; }
    public Routes.DestinationManagement Destination { get; set; }


    public class DestinationManagement
    {
        private DestinationManagement()
        {
            Uri = "/";
            RequiresAuthentication = false;
        }
        public string Uri { get; set; }
        public bool RequiresAuthentication { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Comment: Where is the code where you add those options to the service collection?

Comment: Also Reference [You're using HttpClient wrong](https://aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/)

Comment: In {Startup.ConfigureServices} method => services.AddSingleton<IRoutingService, RoutingService>();

Comment: Yeah but what about adding options? You added the service, not options. Show your configure services method and IConfiguration interactions. update the question with those details.

Comment: Reference [Options pattern in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow steps below to resolve your issue:

1. Register `RouteManagement`

   ```
   services.Configure<RouteManagement>(Configuration.GetSection("routeManagement"));
   ```
2. You need to make `DestinationManagement()` public, otherwise, it will fail to initialize the `DestinationManagement`

   ```
   public class RouteManagement
   {
       public List<Routes> Routes { get; set; }
   }
   public class Routes
   {
       public string Endpoint { get; set; }
       public Routes.DestinationManagement Destination { get; set; }


       public class DestinationManagement
       {
           public DestinationManagement()
           {
               Uri = "/";
               RequiresAuthentication = false;
           }
           public string Uri { get; set; }
           public bool RequiresAuthentication { get; set; }
       }

   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Have you registered the configuration instance which `RouteManagement` binds against in `ConfigureServices` method ?

`services.Configure<RouteManagement>(Configuration);`